# Salesforce Certification ADM201

Tags: certification

I want to take Salesforce Administrator certification. The ADM 201. Is it still called ADM 201 or is it being referred by a different name now. I went into the webassessor to register for the exam. I found this. 
[image]

I just want to confirm whether this is the ADM 201 exam as its not mentioned anywhere there and i don't want to book at a wrong place or exam. If someone helps me confirm this. It will be helpful

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes it is Admin-201.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help. i have successfully passed the exam. I am proud to say that I am salesForce certified

Comment: Many many congratulations!!

Comment: You'd probably do yourself a favor by forget about all the numerical references to exams. Certifications have changed a lot the past year.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be the one, double check by clicking the study guide link. The study guide should let you know.

Actually, I looked at the study guide and it matched the ADM-201 study guide from when I got certified for ADM-201 a year ago.

Looks like Salesforce has recently dropped the numbering convention for exams.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt answer and help. I am planning to take it in a week. hopefully i pass it. It would have been easier if they mentioned it in braces near the exam name.

Comment: The study guide is pretty accurate to what you should expect on the exam. Give the admin trailhead a try if you want to pratice more. Good Luck!

Comment: I completed the admin trails - All three of them . Beginner, intermediate and Advanced. I was not confident enough to give it in the beginning but now i feel a lot more confident to give it a go.

Comment: @Dino good luck for your exam..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the ADM 201. The first credential in the program is the Salesforce Certified Administrator. This credential focuses on the features and functionality used to maintain a Salesforce implementation.

Comment: Thank you Cher. I also got certified a couple of weeks back. Cheers